# Crash when launch Ubuntu, PC OK in Windows

Tags: multi-boot, ubuntu-14.04

To start, here my conf :

```
Nvidia RTX 2080
i5 9600k
16go RAM
Windows 10
Ubuntu 14.04
```

When I select Windows from GRUB, there is no problem; when I pick Ubuntu, it instantly crashes and shows a [loss of video sync.](https://ibb.co/Nnh89h8) This started today.

I'm almost sure there is a conflict with my graphic card. I searched in many forums but this looks new. I tried to launch Ubuntu recovery, but i still get the same screen. I went to the BIOS Setup to see if there is an error but it looks clean.

Thanks for your answers, have a good day.

Comment: Take this opportunity to install a supported release. 14.04 is End of Life.

Comment: Yeah you probably right

Comment: And, maybe a different flavor: https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours